# WCF service cannot be started because the port fetched is already in use

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to get a free TCP port and allocate it to my WCF service to start my application. But the TCP port I fetched is busy at some time and which results in application crashing.

I tried to fetch the TCP port using
   IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties() & allocated it to the service using the below code.

```
private static int FindTCPPort( int startPort = 0)
{
int begin = 49152;
int end = 65535;

IPGlobalProperties properties = 
IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
IPEndPoint[] tcpEndPoints = properties.GetActiveTcpListeners();

List<int> usedPorts = tcpEndPoints.Select(p => p.Port).ToList<int>();
int unusedPort = 0;

for (int port = begin; port < end; port++)
{
   if (!usedPorts.Contains(port))
   {
     unusedPort = port;
     break;
   }
}
return unusedPort;
}
```

Is there any dot net internal class which will get the free ports or though I got the free port from IPGlobalProperties, Is there a way to check if the allocated port is turned into busy in the mean time.

Comment: You might use `TcpListener` try to start listening on some port and if successfull stop and use that port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use this code to get first available port starting from the given port number.
it uses `IPGlobalProperties` to get available

```
public static int GetAvailablePort(int startingPort)
        {
            IPEndPoint[] endPoints;
            List<int> portArray = new List<int>();

            IPGlobalProperties properties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();

            //getting active connections
            TcpConnectionInformation[] connections = properties.GetActiveTcpConnections();
            portArray.AddRange(from n in connections
                               where n.LocalEndPoint.Port >= startingPort
                               select n.LocalEndPoint.Port);

            //getting active tcp listners - WCF service listening in tcp
            endPoints = properties.GetActiveTcpListeners();
            portArray.AddRange(from n in endPoints
                               where n.Port >= startingPort
                               select n.Port);

            //getting active udp listeners
            endPoints = properties.GetActiveUdpListeners();
            portArray.AddRange(from n in endPoints
                               where n.Port >= startingPort
                               select n.Port);

            portArray.Sort();

            for (int i = startingPort; i < UInt16.MaxValue; i++)
                if (!portArray.Contains(i))
                    return i;

            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Reza for your help. Since this issue is not happening all the time, I have to wait for some time to confirm whether the issue is resolved. Once the fix works, I will mark it as answer right away.